# List Item, Two Hyperlinks CSS Design

Tags: html, css

I need to have a single `<li>` element which has two buttons inside of it as follows:

```
<li>
    <a href="#" class="left">The title</a>
    <a href="#" class="right"></a>
</li>
```

With a layout of the button similar to the following:

```
 ____________
|_________|__|
```

The background would span the entire button, the `<a>` tag on the left would be filled with text, the one on the right with an alpha transparent button to overlay the background of the `<li>` element.  This is the CSS I've got.

```
#left ul#main-menu li.li-add a {
    display:block;
    padding:4px 6px 6px 6px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:12px;
    margin:0;
}

#left ul#main-menu li.li-add {
  height:25px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background: url('button_back.gif') no-repeat;
}

#left ul#main-menu li.li-add a.left {
  width:106px;
  float:left;
  padding:5px 6px 6px 6px;
}

#left ul#main-menu li.li-add a.left:hover {
  background: url('button_back_hover.gif') no-repeat;
}

#left ul#main-menu li.li-add a.right {
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:16px;
  padding:4px 0 0 0;
  margin:0;
  height:21px;
  width:27px;
  font-weight:bold;
}

#left ul#main-menu li.li-add a.right:hover {
  background: url('button_back_hover.gif') no-repeat center right;
}
```

I'm doing a similar thing with all the other list items, except they don't have the "add" button on the right hand side.  The problem I'm having is that a two pixel gap is being introduced pushing the other `<li>` elements down.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong really.  I can do `margin-bottom:-2px` but all that does is make an area of 2 pixels which isn't clickable in the element below.

**EDIT**

It was the float actually.

```
#left ul#main-menu li.li-add a.right {
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:16px;
  padding:4px 0 0 0;
  margin:0;
  height:21px;
  width:27px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

`float:left` shouldn't have been in there, for some reason doing this causes an extra gap to be created.  *shrug*.

Comment: Just post your edit as an answer otherwise this keeps showing up as being unsolved/unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your li problem is a red herring.  I was able to have the list layout nice and tight by adding:

```
height: 14px; /* Add to '#left ul#main-menu li.li-add a.left' */
```

You never specified a height for the left a tag, it's auto height was taller than the `25px` specified for the `.right` a tag.  You are setting a height on the li tags, but they are inline elements, not block elements as you've made the a tags.  Only block elements can have specified heights. Hope this helps.

Good luck!